# Django Template, how to parse items with symbols

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have an XML file that I've converted to a python dictionary and passed into a template.  I am attempting to do something like this:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src={{ episode.enclosure.@url }} type={{ episode.enclosure.@type }}>
    Your current browser does not support the audio player.
</audio>
```

The XML file uses @ at the beginning of the key for URL and TYPE.  The problem is, this throws off the parser and crashes the site.  How can I call a key with a symbol like @?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of dictionary with the help of django template tags.

Template tag example

```
@register.filter
def get_attr(obj, attr):
    return obj.get(attr)
```

As you mentioned context is dict therefore I used obj.get but you can use any other methods depending on obj.

Template usage

```
{{ result|get_attr:'@url' }}
```

I defined result in views.py as

```
context = {
        'result' : {'@url':'a123'}
}
```